# PHP Insert Into error.. tried everything

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, sql-insert

probably something stupid as my MySQL PHP knowledge is so rusty.. ive cleaned up all the errors i could and still i cannot write to my DB. Can anyone shed some light on what may be wrong, as its not even printing an error out anymore. Thanks:

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","pe_results"); 


        if (isset($_POST['Name'])) { 
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Short'])) { 
        $Short = $_POST['Short'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Med'])) { 
        $Med = $_POST['Med'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Long'])) { 
        $Long = $_POST['Long'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['VLong'])) { 
        $VLong = $_POST['VLong'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Extreme'])) { 
        $Extreme = $_POST['Extreme'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['LJump'])) { 
        $LJump = $_POST['LJump'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['HJump'])) { 
        $HJump = $_POST['HJump'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Shotputt'])) { 
        $Shotputt = $_POST['Shotputt'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Discuss'])) { 
        $Discuss = $_POST['Discuss'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Javelin'])) { 
        $Javelin = $_POST['Javelin'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Date'])) { 
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Year'])) { 
        $Year = $_POST['Year'];
        }



            $sql="INSERT INTO results_main (Name, Short, Med, Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year)
            VALUES ('$Name', '$Short', '$Med', '$Long', '$VLong', '$Extreme', '$LJump', '$HJump', '$Shotputt', '$Discuss', '$Javelin', '$Date', '$Year')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if($result){
echo"<br/>Everythings been saved";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to the main page</a>";
}

else {
echo 'Fatal Error, you information has not been saved';
}

// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the update:

The query is: INSERT INTO results_main (Name, Short, Med, Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year) VALUES ('Chris Davern', '10:00', '20:00', '40:00', '80:00', '15:00', '100m', '10m', '15m', '50m', '400m', '2013-03-27', '9')

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year) ' at line 1

Comment: What happens when you put a quote in any of your values? `mysql_error` will tell you what your error is.

Comment: If you make your insert statement be $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error()); what does it say? Also mysql* functions are deprecated

Comment: Three important points for you to know: 1) `mysql_query` is deprecated, 2) your code is injection-vulnerable, 3) if you're going to use the deprecated `mysql_` API, then the first step when debugging failing queries is to check the output of `mysql_error()`

Comment: Hi guys, user1048676, doing this comes back saying no database selected? completely stumped. datasage, doing that prints:Notice: Undefined variable: Year in C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 56, although that is the value that i put the quote in

Comment: Also sorry mark, i havent used mysql in such a long time, im not familiar enough with mysqli to try and do it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you aren't selecting a database. Here is how I used to connect with mysql_ functions:

```
$host = "localhost";
$databasename = "pe_results";
$databaseusername = "root";
$databasepassword = "password";

$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$databaseusername", "$databasepassword"); 
mysql_select_db("$databasename", $conn); 

$sql="INSERT INTO results_main (`Name`, `Short`, `Med`, `Long`, `VLong`, `Extreme`, `LJump`, `HJump`, `Shotputt`, `Discuss`, `Javelin`, `Date`, `Year`)
        VALUES ('$Name', '$Short', '$Med', '$Long', '$VLong', '$Extreme', '$LJump', '$HJump', '$Shotputt', '$Discuss', '$Javelin', '$Date', '$Year')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Also please notice that updated the column names because the LONG column name is a mysql keyword so it needs the  to recognize it as a column name instead of a keyword.

Then you can execute your mysql_query. However, like we mentioned earlier. The mysql_ functions are deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: now this happensYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year) ' at line 1

Comment: Echo your query `echo $sql;` before you actually try and execute it and edit your question with what is output from that.

Comment: It just comes up saying that is an undefined variable on line 16 now.. i really am stuck

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern We need to see the query that is trying to be executed. As I said, please echo your sql query and update your question with the output.

Comment: sorry, how exactly do i do this? thank you for your patience, its been a few years since i last did sql work

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern After your query simply add the following line of code `echo 'The query is: '.$sql.'<br><br>;` So add it right above where you have `$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);` This will print the query that is trying to be executed for you.

Comment: keep getting syntax errors when trying to add that line in, had an aerror printed about unexpected whitespace at one point :(

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern Sorry, I forgot to close it. Try this one `echo 'The query is: '.$sql.'<br><br>';`

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern Just out of curosity, try and add a ` to your query. I updated my answer so you can see it. Try that.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for sticking with me man, that all worked. Your amazing, how can I + rep you on here :D

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern You can also upvote the answer but I updated my answer because the column Long is a mysql keyword so that is why you needed to escape it.

Comment: ok. ive now encountered another problem, but thats for another day.. i basically need to insert loads of these results at once but on phpmyadmin it just comes up as blank.. oh well

Answer (score 1):

The word [LONG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-5.0.96) is a reserved word in MySQL... Try wrapping everything in backticks:

```
        $sql="INSERT INTO `results_main` (`Name`, `Short`, `Med`, `Long`, `VLong`, `Extreme`, `LJump`, `HJump`, `Shotputt`, `Discuss`, `Javelin`, `Date`, `Year`)
        VALUES ('$Name', '$Short', '$Med', '$Long', '$VLong', '$Extreme', '$LJump', '$HJump', '$Shotputt', '$Discuss', '$Javelin', '$Date', '$Year')";
```

Instead of

```
        $sql="INSERT INTO results_main (Name, Short, Med, Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year)
        VALUES ('$Name', '$Short', '$Med', '$Long', '$VLong', '$Extreme', '$LJump', '$HJump', '$Shotputt', '$Discuss', '$Javelin', '$Date', '$Year')";
```

Comment: Oops... Looks like @user1048676 already covered that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-connect.php), your 4th argument to `mysql_connect` should be a bollean, I guess it's your DB's name, so you never select any database. Use :

```
mysql_select_db("pe_results");
```

this code may have print this error. :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die (mysql_error ());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this brings me back to square one though, just prints my error message, not completely sure of where to place the $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die (mysql_error ());

Answer (score 0):

You didn't select a database when creating the connection so you can specify it like this:

```
mysql_select_db("Put your Database Name Here");
```

Comment: Still not working man..You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long, VLong, Extreme, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year) ' at line 1